# compare one image in matlab with a database of images and show the most similar

Tags: matlab, image-processing, compare

I have a database of images of one person who is using his hands to show various words and phrases in sign language. The background is white and the only thing changing is the shape of the person's hands and their locations. Now in my gui in matlab, I want the user to be able to choose another image from the same person that was taken at another time doing a sign but wearing the same clothes and then the program will have to compare this against the images in the database and show the most similar. Obviously I can't do pixel by pixel comparison as the images were taken by a hand held mobile camera and slight movement has been inevitable so I should try and locate the hands in the images and compare their shapes. I have no idea how to go about this? I have to say I am new to image processing toolbox in matlab.

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree with you. Such a project can achieve results quickly. 
This becomes a problem as soon as the project has to deal with "real life".

Using a single camera, and a completely known background; Opencv provides a simple way to extract hand shape in a image (in about 20 lines of code). You will find plenty of source on the web (have a look at calcbackproj).
After that, what you will have to do is to play with shape, and search for characteristic points.

Begin with some simple signs (example : a circle and a V). How would you  recognize one from the other?

There are thousands of papers on sign language; just read the older one to simple ideas flowing :)

Comment: Yes, discrimating a "V" from a fist, for instance is defintely doable. But sign language is out of reach....

Comment: Sure, there has been enough work in those subjects to prove that it is not an easy task :). For internships though, one always need a start point with some easy steps !

Comment: Thank you jlengrand. There are two problems though. I only have less than a month and also no experience of c programming. Besides this project has to be done in matlab. Now my question to you guys is that is there a way to detect the hands in the images bearing in mind that the person's clothes and the background are all white (although face would obviously be similar color to hands) and once this is done, how can I possibly compare the shapes of the hands? obviously pixelbypixel comparison wudn't work as the camera angle and distance might have changed a bit in the 2nd round of taking pics.

Comment: As I said, you should start with reading papers. There are plenty of code available for free on the web. Look at the file exchange : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15491-shape-recognition. And Matlab is one of the best tool ever for rapid prototyping (especially if you have the Image Processing toolbox). A simple extraction with thresholding (given strong assertations) and shape recognition could do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing a phD in computer vision, and I can tell you that it is an unsolved problem. (even in your simple framewrok, with white background)

If you are interested, you might read some works about it ar MIT:

http://people.csail.mit.edu/rywang/handtracking/

[image]

or at Oxford:

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/sign_language/index.html

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/hands/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the information. So my guess was right that the lecturer is expecting way too much for an undergraduate degree project